# Simple website: Embedding a button that remembers clicks

Tags: java, html

I am trying to embed a simple "hype" button for my website.

Can someone help me create/embed a button that counts when it is clicked and then remembers and displays that number to anyone who accesses the site? This will work kind of like the SEO share buttons you see on many websites, except it won't link anywhere but instead add 1 to the counter and maybe display a visual effect like confetti.

I am trying to keep this very quick and simple, without self-hosting or anything like that.

Comment: You'll need a server

Comment: Please, read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Because we help you but we don't write code for you. Then I suggest you to read also [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/5533075)